# Publisher Subscriber Model Overloaded Import Names

Tags: python, ros, rospy

So I'm trying to create a program in ROS using Python that publishes images, but I have two things I import that are both called 'Image'. When I run the program, I get this error message.

```
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 812, in __init__
    super(Publisher, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.PUB)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 138, in __init__
    raise ValueError("data_class [%s] is not a class"%data_class) 
ValueError: data_class [<module 'PIL.Image' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc'>] is not a class
```

When I take out the lines importing PIL Image and ImageFilter, the line initializing image1, and the line publishing image1, the program works fine because (I think) there's no confusion between two imported Image objects. Is there a way to tell the program to differentiate between the two Images?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

def camera():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('rgb', Image, queue_size=10)
    image1 = Image.open('dog.png')
    pub.publish(image1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        camera()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename things during import:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image as ImageMsg
```

This way you can avoid the name collision.

Comment: Apart from that, there are more bugs in your code: 1) you don't initialize a ros node (using `rospy.init_node()` and 2) you cannot directly publish a PIL image but you have to convert it to a ROS image message.